# How to create a text with a bounding box of a background color using Constrained layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-constraintlayout

What I want to achieve is following result using a constraint layout inside a parent window:
[image]

I had seen in a udacity android tutorial that this can be achieved by using an ImageView and TextView with constraints specified for TextView wrt to ImageView.But this was achieved without hard-coding the dimensions of the box (i.e width and height of ImageView was set to 0dp each and ImageView expanded just using constraints.)

I tried following and it is not giving proper results:

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTable"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/imageViewTable"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/imageViewTable"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageViewTable"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageViewTable"
    />
```

I know there is a simple way to do it using padding , but I want to know how it can be done like this way (using 0dp imageview)

Comment: why don't you make a textview with padding and a green background?

Comment: @Tiago I know it can be done like that.But I want to know that 'trick' to use a 0dp ImageView.I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:visibility="visible"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textViewTest"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewTest"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTest"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewTest" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextVigjsdgjew"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I think in this case the dimensions of the ImageView is fixed and not dependent on TextView size.So it might not serve my purpose.I found the way to do it.I will update with the answer later.

Comment: @banguru, I am sorry I couldn't get your question first time. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes , you are right.I think you need to remove 0dp margins (android:layout_marginTop="0dp" etc) , otherwise the view will stretch entire window!Please correct it , I will accept as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Tiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168707/how-to-create-a-text-with-a-bounding-box-of-a-background-color-using-constrained#comment73411848_43168707), all you need is to remove `imageViewTable` and change `textViewTest` in the following way:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
```

Comment: I know it can be done like that.But I want to know that 'trick' to use a 0dp ImageView.I have edited the question to reflect this.